# I wish to "console.log("Yes!");" for a limited number of elements in an array, but it`s not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display `console.log("Yes");` for every 4 inside my array in JavaScript, but instead I'm getting displayed `Yes!` for every single element of the array! How could I fix this?

Tried googleing for a solution, but didn`t come up with much...

```js
var newArr = [1, 2, 5, 9, 4, 13, 4, 10];

    for(e = 0; e < newArr.length; e++)   {
        if(newArr.includes(4))  {
            console.log("Yes!");
        }
    }
```

I`m getting`Yes!` displayed 8 times, instead only 2 times.

Comment: Take it out of the loop.

Comment: `if(newArr.includes(4)) ...` → `if (newArr[e] === 4) ...`

Comment: Maybe you want to replace `newArr.includes(4)` by `newArr[e] === 4`?. Note that `Array.includes()` will check if the array includes the element, so will be `true` on every iteration.

Comment: Thanks guys! You solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you every time that array loops try to print if array does have '4' or not and 8 times you loop and the answer is yes it does.

so what you wanna do is probably this ( in your condition ) :

```
if(newArr[e]==4){
    console.log("Yes!");
}
```

Comment: You're wellcome